# C#. Encode text without tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have text with custom tags. Text can also contains symbols '<', '<<<<<', '>', '"' etc. 
I need encode all text without tags.
Example of text:

```
The Stack Exchange network is a set of  Q&A sites dedicated to providing high-quality questions and answers, with the modest goal of making the Internet a better place. It is owned and operated by Stack Exchange Inc.
>>>>>>>>>We take the private nature of your personal information very seriously, and are committed to protecting it.
<helplink id="123456"/>
To do that, we’ve set up procedures to ensure that your information is handled responsibly and in accordance with applicable data protection and privacy laws. We’re grateful for your trust, and we’ll act that way.
```

I think that need use regular expression to find text without tags.

Comment: That is a little strange, usually non-tag items are presented as html attributes, &gt;, &lt;, etc

Comment: You mean you are trying to parse HTML documents and want to remove the tags?

Comment: No. I need to encode text and save existing tags

Comment: Perhaps a "before" and "after" example would make things clearer? At the moment that is a very odd mix of raw text (`Q&A`, i.e. not html), markup (`<helplink .../>`) and "something else" (`>>>>>>>>`)

Comment: Is there any reference to this pattern?